# Hybrid mobile application development using Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, native, hybrid-mobile-app

What are the pros and cons of creating hybrid mobile applications compaired to writing native IOS and Android Apps?

I'm considering writing hybrid mobile apps using Javascript and HTML. Then generate the IOS and Android deployment packages from the same code. I'm considering using Cordova Javascript to generate calls to the native device hardware (cameras, microphone etc).

Are there any gotya's with using Cordova or the hybrid approach in general?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap Vs native iOS/Android development in 2014](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219573/phonegap-vs-native-ios-android-development-in-2014)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage to using something like Phonegap (or just Cordova) is that you get one codebase to update leading to easier maintenance and update pushes. If you use javascript animation libraries, like Velocity, you can get very performant, app like UI elements.

The biggest downside argued by natvie developers is performance. They will tell you natvie is faster. That you can't get the same performance out of just Javascript. I think thats a bit of a straw man. As mentioned, there are very performant JS animation libraries.

This is of course is just a cursory dive into the differences. This topic has been debated at length but these are generally the most important differences.